# how to add custom field in order grid magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add the custom field in  order grid page in Magento Backend.

Comment: Is that custom field is part of order?

Comment: yes it is part of order  I want to add simple input field

Comment: I post answer. please check.

Answer (score -1):

You want to follow this steps.

1. rewrite order grid block into your custom extension. For that enter this code into `config.xml`

   ```
   <blocks>
      <adminhtml>
         <rewrite>
             <sales_order_grid>Vendor_Extension_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
         </rewrite>
     </adminhtml>
   </blocks>
   ```
2. Now create that grid file with custom field.

   ```
   <?php
   class Vendor_Extension_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
   {
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
       $this->setUseAjax(true);
       $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
       $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
       $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
   }

    protected function _getCollectionClass()
   {
       return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
   }

   protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
       $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

       //we changed mysql query, we added inner join to order item table
       $collection->join('sales/order_item', 'order_id=entity_id', array('name'=>'name', 'custom_field' => 'custom_field', 'qty_ordered'=>'qty_ordered' ), null,'left');
       $this->setCollection($collection);
       return parent::_prepareCollection();
   }

   protected function _prepareColumns()
   {

       $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
           'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
           'width' => '80px',
           'type'  => 'text',
           'index' => 'increment_id',
       ));

       if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
           $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
               'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased from (store)'),
               'index'     => 'store_id',
               'type'      => 'store',
               'store_view'=> true,
               'display_deleted' => true,
               'filter_index' => 'main_table.store_id'
           ));
       }

       $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
           'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
           'index' => 'created_at',
           'type' => 'datetime',
           'width' => '100px',
           'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at'
       ));

       $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
           'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
           'index' => 'billing_name',
       ));

       $this->addColumn('qty_ordered', array(
           'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Items Ordered'),
           'index'     => 'qty_ordered',
           'type'      => 'number',
           'total'     => 'sum'
       ));

       $this->addColumn('custom_field', array(
           'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('CUSTOM LABEL'),
           'index'     => 'custom_field',
           'type' => 'text'
       ));

       $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
           'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
           'index' => 'base_grand_total',
           'type'  => 'currency',
           'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
       ));

       $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
           'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
           'index' => 'grand_total',
           'type'  => 'currency',
           'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
       ));

       $this->addColumn('status', array(
           'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
           'index' => 'status',
           'type'  => 'options',
           'width' => '70px',
           'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
       ));


       return $this;
   }

   protected function _prepareMassaction()
   {
       $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
       $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
       $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

       if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
           $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
           ));
       }

       if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
           $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
           ));
       }

       if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
           $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
           ));
       }

       $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
       ));

       $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
       ));

       $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
       ));

       $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
       ));

       return $this;
   }

   public function getRowUrl($row)
   {
       if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
           return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
       }
       return false;
   }
   public function getGridUrl()
   {
       return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: can you tell me step by step please

Comment: There are just two steps. You need to add these steps to any custom extension. And replace that extension path into above code.

Comment: i will make the extension for  it

Comment: Ok, you can. I share the main code which you want for your problem.

Comment: its job matter please

Comment: This link hel you, how to create extension.
https://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/
https://magenticians.com/create-magento-custom-module/

Comment: I need to input field on order view page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82190/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-monu-kumar).